# Excel VBA For Loop for Volume Calculation

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a program that will allow agricultural producers easily calculate a volume of a tank. I specifically want them to be able to input multiple dimensions for their tanks and calculate the volume of each tank individually. The dimensions will be separated by a comma and I want them to be split and put into their own column. I then want excel to take each column of data and apply the volume formula to get the volume of the cylinder. I am not sure how to do that though, and I feel a loop will be needed to go through each column i.e. column 1 volume, column 2 volume, etc.The code for that is below.

```
'Seperates values that are seperated by a comma and then puts them in their own column
Public Sub CommaSep()
    Selection.TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Columns(3), _
      DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=True, _
      Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, _
      Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, _
      OtherChar:=","
End Sub
```

The code for the tank dimensions is

```
Public Sub NoInput()

Sheets.Add.Name = "Hidden Information"

Worksheets(2).Activate

Dim tankCount As Integer
tankCount = Application.InputBox("Enter the Number of Tanks that will be in the Secondary Containment", "Known Tank Quantity", 1)
If tankCount = False Then
    Call DeleteSheets
    Exit Sub
Else
    tankTotal = tankCount
End If

Dim knownVol As Variant
knownVol = Application.InputBox("Enter the Known Volume of the Tank in Gallons. If volume is not known then enter 0", "Known Tank Volume", 0)
If knownVol = "" Then
    Call DeleteSheets
    Exit Sub
ElseIf knownVol > 0 Then
    Application.Worksheets(1).Range("A6").Value = "Known Tank Volume"
    Application.Worksheets(1).Range("B6").Value = knownVol
'    Application.Worksheets(2).Range("A6").Value = "Known Tank Volume"
'    Application.Worksheets(2).Range("B6").Value = knownVol
'    Call SPCCSizedSecondary
'    Exit Sub
Else
End If


Dim diameter As Variant
diameter = Application.InputBox("Enter the Diameter of the Tanks in feet seperated by commas", "Diameter", 1)
If diameter = False Then
    Call DeleteSheets
    Exit Sub
Else
    Application.Worksheets(1).Range("A4").Value = "Diameter"
    Application.Worksheets(1).Range("B4").Value = diameter
End If


Dim length As Variant
length = Application.InputBox("Enter the Length of the Tanks in feet seperated by commas", "Length", 1)
If length = False Then
    Call DeleteSheets
    Exit Sub
Else
    Application.Worksheets(1).Range("A5").Value = "Length"
    Application.Worksheets(1).Range("B5").Value = length
End If

'Dim knownVol As Variant
'knownVol = Application.InputBox("Enter the Known Volume(s) of the Tank in Gallons seperated by commas. If volume is not known then enter 0", "Known Tank Volume", 0)
'If knownVol = False Then
'    Call DeleteSheets
'    Exit Sub
'Else
'    Application.Worksheets(1).Range("A6").Value = "Known Tank Volume"
'    Application.Worksheets(1).Range("B6").Value = knownVol
'End If

Columns(1).AutoFit
Columns(2).AutoFit

'Call DeleteSheets

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your description of what you were looking to do, I built a mock up to (hopefully) provide some guidance. I'm by no means an expert, so I'm sure there's a better way to do all of this; also, there's basically no validation going on here, so be wary.

> The dimensions will be separated by a comma and I want them to be split and put into their own column.

If you're accepting inputs separated by commas, I say take that input and split it into an array. I'm assuming the length/diameters will need precision, so I used these two functions to convert a comma separated string input into an array of doubles

```
Function csv_to_string_array(strCSV as String) As String()
    csv_to_string_array = Split("," & strCSV, ",") 'don't know why, but needs a leading comma otherwise it skips the first input
End Function

Function str_to_double_array(strArray() as String) As Double()
    Dim tempDblArray() As Double
    ReDim tempDblArray(UBound(strArray))

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(strArray)
        tempDblArray(i) = CDbl(strArray(i))
    Next i

    str_to_double_array = tempDblArray()
End Function
```

Then I used them like this to fill my doubles array (using the input from InputBox)

```
dblDiameter() = str_to_double_array(csv_to_string_array(strInputDiameter))
```

> I then want excel to take each column of data and apply the volume
>   formula to get the volume of the cylinder.

I made a function for this too, since it seemed like it made sense. Feel free to make pi more accurate if you want.

```
Function calc_cylinder_volume(dblDiameter as Double, dblLength as Double) As Double
    calc_cylinder_volume = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi() * ((dblDiameter ^ 2) / 4) * dblLength)
End Function
```

With those, I set up a `NoInput` similar to yours to accept the input and dump the values and volume calculations. It doesn't do anything too radical, just starts in `A1` and drops a row for each diameter and length input, then calculates a volume for each.

Here's the whole thing all together. You can just copy all of the code here into a single Module and run `NoInput()` to kick it off.

```
Option Explicit

Sub NoInput()
    Dim strInputDiameter As String
    strInputDiameter = Application.InputBox("Tank Diameter") 'get diameter inputs

    Dim strInputLength As String
    strInputLength = Application.InputBox("Tank Length") 'get length inputs

    'convert comma separated inputs to arrays of Doubles
    Dim dblDiameter() As Double
    dblDiameter() = str_to_double_array(csv_to_string_array(strInputDiameter))
    Dim dblLength() As Double
    dblLength() = str_to_double_array(csv_to_string_array(strInputLength))


    Dim rngCurrCell As Range
    Set rngCurrCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    'set number of containers to whichever input had the least values
    Dim intContainerCount As Integer
    intContainerCount = WorksheetFunction.Min(UBound(dblDiameter), UBound(dblLength))

    'calculate volume for each container, output to sheet
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To intContainerCount
        rngCurrCell.Value = "Diameter " & i
        rngCurrCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = dblDiameter(i)

        rngCurrCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "Length " & i
        rngCurrCell.Offset(1, 1).Value = dblLength(i)

        rngCurrCell.Offset(2, 0).Value = "Volume " & i
        rngCurrCell.Offset(2, 1).Value = calc_cylinder_volume(dblDiameter(i), dblLength(i))

        Set rngCurrCell = rngCurrCell.Offset(0, 3)
    Next i
End Sub

Function csv_to_string_array(strCSV As String) As String()
    csv_to_string_array = Split("," & strCSV, ",") 'don't know why, but needs a leading comma otherwise it skips the first input
End Function

Function str_to_double_array(strArray() As String) As Double()
    Dim tempDblArray() As Double
    ReDim tempDblArray(UBound(strArray))

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(strArray)
        tempDblArray(i) = CDbl(strArray(i))
    Next i

    str_to_double_array = tempDblArray()
End Function

Function calc_cylinder_volume(dblDiameter As Double, dblLength As Double) As Double
    calc_cylinder_volume = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi() * ((dblDiameter ^ 2) / 4) * dblLength)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I guess due to my newness to the whole Excel VBA programming, I'm not too sure how to implement a function into my routine. I am only used to using a Sub instead of a Function. Could you give me a idea of how to use it within the macro im creating?

Comment: @JuliusDariusBelosarius I'll add an edit to clarify how to put everything here together. To use the function, you would just need to copy and paste it beneath your Sub; so copy the entire function from Function to End Function, and paste directly beneath your last End Sub. Then, you can just reference the function within your Sub, like `calc_cylinder_volume(dblDiameter(i), dblLength(i))`

Comment: Just to add you can use: Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi() to obtain Pi

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation! I appreciate it greatly. I also learned about functions which is great, as it makes me think of the days where I learned MATLAB. I think I can carry on now with this project.

Comment: Isn't cylinder volume Pi * (diameter^2)/4 * length?

Comment: Yes it is. I had already made the change for that! But good looking out.

Comment: @WillBeDeleted It is? What am I Googling wrong then, because all my results don't include any dividing by 4

Comment: The volume of a cylinder with the radius is pi*radius^2*height. The volume when given the diameter is pi*(diameter^2)/4*height. This is because the radius = 2*diameter so diameter is diameter = radius / 2. Then you plug that in and get  pi*(diameter^2)/4*height. Still appreciated all the help

Comment: @JuliusDariusBelosarius Ah yes, I must've completely forgotten that radius and diameter were different things somehow

Comment: @Etheur, back to school with you :-)